# Bootstrap сетка - почему не работает?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Почему моя сетка (`.row` со всеми `.col-md`) выходит за границы родительского контейнера?

```css
.mixer {
  width: 1024px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid #6B70F0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="mixer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <p>Настройте и скачайте свою минусовку:</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <button class="playbtn"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Оформил ваш код так, чтобы его можно было выполнить и посмотреть результат. Добавьте в него ваши стили. Без них мы не увидим вашей проблемы.

Comment: пока только один стиль, для родительского контейнера. Добавил

Comment: @PolonskiyP Добавил ответ, вы так хотите?

Answer (score 1):

так все работает

```
.container
{
  background: red; 
  width: 1019px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы сделали два вложенных контейнера. У блока с классом `.mixer` ширина фиксирована, а у блока с классом `.container` – [зависит от ширины экрана](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options).

Поэтому на узком экране блок с классом `.mixer` выходит за границу экрана. А на экранах шириной от `1200px` блок с классом `.container` оказывается шире, чем блок с классом `.mixer` и выходит за его границу.

Исправлять можно разными способами – в зависимости от вашей задачи. Например, можно добавить обоим контейнерам ограничение по ширине:

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.container, 
.mixer {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.mixer {
  width: 1024px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid #6B70F0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container mixer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <p>Настройте и скачайте свою минусовку:</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <button class="playbtn"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Но мне кажется, что код станет понятнее, если оформить класс `.mixer` как модификатор класса `.container`. А `1024px` задать как `max-width`.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.container.mixer {
  max-width: 1024px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid #6B70F0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container mixer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <p>Настройте и скачайте свою минусовку:</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <button class="playbtn"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что разметка использующая `float` не гарантирует нахождение элементов на одной строке, поэтому используйте flexbox. Добавьте осмысленный класс (подходящий семантически) для `.row`, к примеру, `music-container` и добавьте ему `display: flex;`. Чтобы кнопка была справа, можно просто её контейнеру присвоить `margin-left: auto;`.

Готовый пример:

```css
.mixer {
  width: 1024px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid #6B70F0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.music-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.playbtn-container {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="mixer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row music-container">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <p>Настройте и скачайте свою минусовку:</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 playbtn-container">
        <button class="playbtn"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: В вашем исправлении не работают col-md-10 и col-md-2. Проинспектируйте. Ведь row значительно шире!

Comment: Это даже невооруженным глазом видно. Button должен быть значительно правее

Comment: @PolonskiyP Это что-то с `bootstrap`. Почему-то я не вижу чтобы у стилей `col-md-10`, `col-md-2` была ширина в процентах.

Comment: @PolonskiyP Добавил решение, которое не зависит от boostrap (но ему не противоречит).

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Поищите `col-md-10` и `col-md-2` в https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css